# Changing translucent background color of progressbar android

Tags: android, android-alertdialog, android-progressbar

I want to change background color of the progressbar having black translucent background with opacity less than 50%. 
I searched a lot about this but not able to find solution. 
I don't know whether i'm right or not but it has some thing to do with mdecor property of the progressbar.

Following is the code I am using it.

```
pd = ProgressDialog.show(getActivity(), null, null,true);       
pd.setContentView(R.layout.remove_border);
```

The code for remove border layout is:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@android:color/transparent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<ProgressBar
    android:id="@+id/progressBar1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:background="@android:color/transparent"
    android:indeterminateDrawable="@drawable/my_progress_indeterminate" />

</LinearLayout>
```

The code for my_progress_indeterminate is:

```
<animated-rotate xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:drawable="@drawable/loadingiconblack"
android:pivotX="50%"
android:pivotY="50%" />
```

Following is the image the background area is marked in red circle. I want to change color to white with same opacity.

[image]

**EDIT:**

**Final solution to my issue thanks to Sripathi and user3298272 combining both solutions here is my updated answer:**

```
pd = new Dialog(this, android.R.style.Theme_Black);
View view = LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(R.layout.remove_border, null);
pd.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
pd.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawableResource(R.color.transparent);
pd.setContentView(view);
pd.show();
```

remove_border xml code:
Here android:gravity = "center" is added in linear layout code of mine.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@android:color/transparent"
android:gravity="center"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<ProgressBar
    android:id="@+id/progressBar1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:background="@android:color/transparent"
    android:indeterminateDrawable="@drawable/my_progress_indeterminate" />

</LinearLayout>
```

color xml code:

```
<resources>

  <color name="transparent">#80FFFFFF</color>

</resources>
```

In #80FFFFFF 80 is the opacity value 50% which i took from user3298272.

Comment: progressDialog.setFeatureDrawableAlpha(featureId, alpha);

Comment: @Sripathi what will be the value for featureid ?

Comment: id of the drawable you wish to set as background. From docs, featureId The desired drawable feature to change. Features are constants defined by Window.
alpha The alpha amount, 0 is completely transparent and 255 is completely opaque.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use dialog instead of progressdialog,

```
    dialogTransparent = new Dialog(this, android.R.style.Theme_Black);
    View view = LayoutInflater.from(getActivity()).inflate(
            R.layout.remove_border, null);
    dialogTransparent.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    dialogTransparent.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawableResource(
            R.color.transparent);
    dialogTransparent.setContentView(view);
```

**Update:**

```
   Here the color transparent is  #80FFFFFF
```

Comment: i tired your setbackgrounddrawableresource code it only affects that circular area of progressbar and makes the background white.Its not affecting the background i marked in red

Comment: will implement and let you know, but can you tell me R.style.theme_black will affect color of the background na?

Comment: Nope that will not make impact.

Comment: the issue is the progress dialog is in class which extends fragment so its giving error for "this" in your code.

Comment: I am getting the background color in white but the opacity is not the same as i marked in red in image i uploaded and the progress animated circle appears at center-top position of screen.

Comment: I got my solution accepted your answer but want to put exact changes where should i put it?

Comment: You can align the loading wheel to the center. In my case its working fine. Searching the reason for the failure.. Get you back with the answer..

Comment: Can you please format your answer I used majority of your code and some bit of @user3298272 suggestion for opacity.
following is my code:

pd = new Dialog(getActivity(), android.R.style.Theme_Black);
   View view = LayoutInflater.from(getActivity()).inflate(R.layout.remove_border, null);
   pd.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
   pd.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawableResource(R.color.transparent);
pd.setContentView(view);
pd.show();

Adding android:gravity="center" in linearlayout of remove_border xml

changing color code in R.color.transparent with #80FFFFFF for 50% opacity

Comment: Have you got succeed with that?

Comment: yes the above changes are what i made in my code and its providing me what i wanted.

Comment: For my sided its working perfect. You can change your transparent color as you want. I don't know what you mean by formatting code.

Answer (score 15):

Here is the transparent color ratio for the Hex color codes.
100% — FF
95% — F2
90% — E6
85% — D9
80% — CC
75% — BF
70% — B3
65% — A6
60% — 99
55% — 8C
50% — 80
45% — 73
40% — 66
35% — 59
30% — 4D
25% — 40
20% — 33
15% — 26
10% — 1A
5% — 0D
0% — 00
 Just add the percentage of opacity before the color code. **For example** : color code for black is #0000. If i want transparent black with **50%** transparency means just add **80** before #0000(i.e. **#800000**)

Comment: I don't know from where to change the color. Any property or example code is appreciated.

Comment: Just set background color in xml. android:background="#BF0000" for 75% transparency instead of     android:background="@android:color/transparent"

Comment: I have set @android:color/transparent for background color as the backgroundcolor only affects the progress bar circluar image and not whole screen background.

Comment: fix transparency manually instead of     android:background="@android:color/transparent" and check for any lucks.

Comment: you try with 100% transparency by adding FF along with your color code.

Comment: tweak your code the color # should be total of 8 chc where 1st and 2nd chc will be opacity value and rest 6 will be color code.

Answer (score 3):

Just set
    progressBar.setAlpha(0.2f);