# How to Get Semi-Transparent Layout for Progress Bar

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, android-fragments

I'd like to display a temporary spinning progress indicator on a fragment of my app when fetching data.  So far I've gotten it to work great, but the background is solid black when I want to have the regular page content grayed out when the indicator is visible.  What I've tried is to add a new full-screen layout with a semi-transparent black background on top of my existing layouts, but no matter what I try I only get a black background.  I've also tried a FrameLayout container but this has only given a 100% transparent layout.

I've even read this post but it just doesn't work:
[Changing translucent background color of progressbar android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23869248/changing-translucent-background-color-of-progressbar-android)

Code for fragment xml layout file: (the table is populated dynamically)

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="match_parent"
              android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
              android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
              android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
              android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
              tools:context="com.ericbatemandev.lemanskarting.view.League"
              android:background="#000"
              android:orientation="vertical">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:id="@+id/pageLoading"
        android:background="@color/transparent">

        <ProgressBar
            style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleLarge"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/progressBar"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"/>
    </RelativeLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="64dp"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Pro Enduro League Standings"
            android:id="@+id/leaguePageTitle"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            android:textColor="#fff"
            android:background="@drawable/page_title_background"
            android:textStyle="bold"/>
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <ScrollView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:id="@+id/scrollView">

            <TableLayout
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/leagueResultsTable">

                <TableRow
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent">

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="80dp"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="Standing"
                        android:id="@+id/standingLabel"
                        android:textStyle="bold"
                        android:textSize="16sp"
                        android:textColor="#fff"/>

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="200dp"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="Team Name"
                        android:id="@+id/teamNameLabel"
                        android:textColor="#fff"
                        android:textSize="16sp"
                        android:textStyle="bold"/>

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="55dp"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="Points"
                        android:id="@+id/pointsLabel"
                        android:textStyle="bold"
                        android:textSize="16sp"
                        android:textColor="#fff"/>
                </TableRow>

            </TableLayout>
        </ScrollView>
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Color from colors.xml

```
    <color name="transparent">#80000000</color>
```

I'm calling the layout in my fragment like this:

```
    public void showLoadingIndicator() {
        RelativeLayout pageLoading = (RelativeLayout)llLayout.findViewById(R.id.pageLoading);
        pageLoading.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }

    public void hideLoadingIndicator() {
        RelativeLayout pageLoading = (RelativeLayout)llLayout.findViewById(R.id.pageLoading);
        pageLoading.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }
```

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: I think this has got something to do with styles. Whats your minSDK level and which theme do you use.

Comment: I just figured out that the RelativeLayout with the progress indicator was pushing down the other Layouts beyond the bottom of the screen.  So now my issue is that I need to stack the RelativeLayout on top of the others. Min SDK is API 15, and theme is basically blank at this point.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just solved this using FrameLayout as the parent.  The key thing that I didn't do before was put the RelativeLayout holding the progress indicator LAST in the tree, instead of first.  The layout isn't perfect, but I now have the semi-transparent effect I was looking for.

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="match_parent"
          android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
          android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
          android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
          android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
          tools:context="com.ericbatemandev.lemanskarting.view.League"
          android:background="#000"
          android:orientation="vertical">

<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="64dp"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Pro Enduro League Standings"
        android:id="@+id/leaguePageTitle"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:textColor="#fff"
        android:background="@drawable/page_title_background"
        android:textStyle="bold"/>
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/scrollView">

        <TableLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/leagueResultsTable">

            <TableRow
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent">

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="80dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Standing"
                    android:id="@+id/standingLabel"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
                    android:textSize="16sp"
                    android:textColor="#fff"/>

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="200dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Team Name"
                    android:id="@+id/teamNameLabel"
                    android:textColor="#fff"
                    android:textSize="16sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold"/>

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="55dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Points"
                    android:id="@+id/pointsLabel"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
                    android:textSize="16sp"
                    android:textColor="#fff"/>
            </TableRow>

        </TableLayout>
    </ScrollView>
</LinearLayout>

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:id="@+id/pageLoading"
    android:background="@color/transparent">

    <ProgressBar
        style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleLarge"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/progressBar4"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:background="#00000000"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```