# Why circular progressBar background not showing?

Tags: android, android-progressbar

This is my style_circular_fill.xml file

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item android:id="@android:id/progress">
    <rotate
        android:fromDegrees="270"
        android:pivotX="50%"
        android:pivotY="50%"
        android:toDegrees="270" >
        <shape
            android:innerRadiusRatio="3"
            android:shape="ring"
            android:thicknessRatio="14.0"
            android:useLevel="true">
            <gradient
                android:centerColor="#A9E2F3"
                android:endColor="#A9E2F3"
                android:startColor="#A9E2F3"
                android:type="sweep" />
        </shape>
    </rotate>
</item>

<item android:id="@android:id/background">
    <shape
        android:innerRadiusRatio="3"
        android:shape="ring"
        android:thicknessRatio="14.0"
        android:useLevel="false">

        <gradient
            android:centerColor="#FFF"
            android:endColor="#FFF"
            android:startColor="#FFF"
            android:type="sweep" />

    </shape>
</item>
```

And here is the progressbar in my activity.xml file

```
<ProgressBar
    android:id="@+id/progressBar1"
    style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"
    android:layout_width="300dp"
    android:layout_height="300dp"
    android:indeterminate="false"
    android:progressDrawable="@drawable/style_circular_fill"
    android:max="100"
    android:progress="10" />
```

And here is the result:

[image]

I don't know why the white circle background is not showing up...
Are there anything that I did wrong in either of the .xml file?

Comment: you can set the background colour to be transparent, some examples [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23869248/changing-translucent-background-color-of-progressbar-android)

Answer (score 0):

You can use [this](https://github.com/DreaminginCodeZH/MaterialProgressBar) library for your material design progress bar.

eg:

```
<me.zhanghai.android.materialprogressbar.MaterialProgressBar
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:indeterminate="true"
app:mpb_progressStyle="horizontal"
style="@style/Widget.MaterialProgressBar.ProgressBar.Horizontal" />
```

Answer (score 0):

I have split your selector into 2 different drawables and set one for background and the other one for progressDrawable and it seems to work fine.

```
<ProgressBar
    android:id="@+id/progressBar1"
    style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"
    android:layout_width="300dp"
    android:layout_height="300dp"
    android:indeterminate="false"
    android:progressDrawable="@drawable/style_circular_fill"
    android:background="@drawable/background_circular"
    android:max="100"
    android:progress="20" />
```

in style_circular_fill :

```
<rotate xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:fromDegrees="270"
    android:pivotX="50%"
    android:pivotY="50%"
    android:toDegrees="270" >
    <shape
        android:innerRadiusRatio="3"
        android:shape="ring"
        android:thicknessRatio="14.0"
        android:useLevel="true">
        <gradient
            android:centerColor="#A9E2F3"
            android:endColor="#A9E2F3"
            android:startColor="#A9E2F3"
            android:type="sweep" />
    </shape>
</rotate>
```

in background_circular :

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:innerRadiusRatio="3"
    android:shape="ring"
    android:thicknessRatio="14.0"
    android:useLevel="false">

    <gradient
        android:centerColor="#FFF"
        android:endColor="#FFF"
        android:startColor="#FFF"
        android:type="sweep" />

</shape>
```