# How to remove the progress Bar background colour?

Tags: android

How to remove the progress Bar background Dim colour in android while showing progress bar or alert dialog.

[image]

Comment: Try this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23869248/changing-translucent-background-color-of-progressbar-android

Answer (score 0):

Use Background Drawable.

Use RGBA Color Hexcode. Like #FFFFFFFF

First 2  Charcters Shows intensity of Red.
3 and 4 For Green 
5 and 6 for Blue
7 and 8 for the Alpha Layer (Helps in Tranparency)